# How to optimize multi-processing in Python with Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I know there are several tutorials out there for multiprocessing in python.
Anyways, I just want to ask you for my specific use case.
So here is my setup:

- I have a machine with 8 physical cores and 32 GB RAM and
- I have a pickle dict with 8 GB of text holding 3.000.000 entries.

Now the question is, how would I get the most juice out of my CPU?

```py
data = pickle.load(handle)
dict_list = split_dict_equally(data, 16) # split data into 16 equal chunks
with Pool(16) as pool:
        data = pool.map(func, dict_list)
```

For each element in the dict an external package is used to send requests which is the time-intensive part I want to speed up.

If I use the setup defined above on a smaller sample (100 entries) I am able to reduce the execution-time of the script from 72 sec to 6 secs. However, I doubt that the same setup is reducing execution time for the large dataset.
The reason I believe this is that when I look in the Activity Meter Manger, only just under 10% of the CPU is being used. The question is therefore, what is the optimal split size of the dict relative to the proceessing units used defined within the pool instance given the large pickle file?

I'd really appricate it, if you could help me speed it up, thanks.

Comment: I would have expected disk read to be the bottleneck here, not CPU.

Comment: Intersting hint. RAM is at 25 GB / 32 GB. Any ideas how to speed it up?

Comment: probably faster to do this in a single thread.  Transmitting a huge `dict_list` to 16 processes along with returning results is a lot of overhead.  Anyway, try something and measure.